# Dragging/moving form inside a form causes it to leave traces

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I made a "borderless" form named Form2 with few components to give it some functionality and set it's parent to Form1 "**which has a background image set**". I've also set `DoubleBuffer=True` in both Form2 and Form1 to avoid flickers. When I drag or move Form2, it leaves traces or look response less(as if there's some graphics issue) until I leave the mouse. I've also used `Refresh()`, `Invalidate()` and `Update()`, still the same thing. Is there a fix to this issue?

**EDIT 1:**
Look's something this

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class Form1
 Inherits Form
 Public Sub New()
  DoubleBuffer=True
 End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
 Inherits Form
 Public Sub New()
  DoubleBuffer=True
  TopLevel=False
 End Sub
End Class

Module MainApp
 Dim Form1 As New Form1
 Dim Form2 As New Form2
 Sub Main()
  With Form2
   Form1.Controls.Add(Form2)
   .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
   Form1.BackgroungImage = My.Resources.ImageResurce.IMG_1
   Form1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
   .Show
   Form1.Show
   AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf Drag
   AddHandler .MouseUp, AddressOf Drag
   AddHandler .MouseMove, AddressOf Drag
  End With
  Do
   Application.DoEvents()
  Loop
 End Sub
 Sub Drag(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  'Code to drag form2
 End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: We should never have to say this but show us the code.

Comment: What kind of Project is this? Did you disable the ApplicationFramework of a Windows Forms Project or is it something else? Do you have Application.Run() somewhere? No? That's why you're trying to call `Application.DoEvents()` in a loop? How can you handle `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` events with a single handler? `Dim Form1 As New Form1`: bad idea.

Comment: + `Public Class MainApp [...] Sub Main() [...]` <- No, really not.

Comment: It's a blank VB.NET Project, BTW I was in a rush writing this question.

Comment: + `DoubleBuffer = True` <- What? At least, post real code.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` in the loop is to prevent the app from closing. @Jimi, I know that `MouseDown` , `MouseUp ` and `MouseMove` has different handlers, but I didn't understand why `Dim Form1 As New Form1` is a bad idea, because the class `Form1` inherits the `Form` class so the class `Form1` has the same functionality as a normal form. I'm going for an advanced approach instead of dragging items into the form in the IDE

Comment: Just realized that I've written `Public Class MainApp`, which is actually `Module MainApp`. My bad :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212594/discussion-between-mhi2002-and-jimi).